# Identify a pre-8th edition black creature card

Tags: magic-the-gathering, identify-this-game-piece

I'm looking for a Magic The Gathering card that was very sought for back in high school. It was certainly not later than 8th edition era, black colored creature. I remember the art was something similar to [Bog Initiate](https://scryfall.com/card/inv/95/bog-initiate) but it had an ability set similar to [Cromat](https://scryfall.com/card/apc/94/cromat), so it must have been at least Uncommon.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you asking what it was called / looked like, or are you asking where you can buy one?

Comment: I can only find two black creatures other than Cromat from before 8th edition that had at least 3 activated abilities, and neither has art that looks very much like Bog Initiate to me: [Vaevictis Asmadi](https://scryfall.com/card/me3/185/vaevictis-asmadi) and [Wandering Mage](https://scryfall.com/card/me3/186/wandering-mage).

Comment: What does "similar to cromat" mean here? Does that just mean multiple activated abilities, or that the abilities didn't require tapping, or that all the abilities had off-color activation costs?

Comment: [There are 190 black creature cards printed before 8th Edition that have an activated ability whose rarity is uncommon or above.](https://scryfall.com/search?q=date%3C8ed+t%3Acreature+c%3Ab+fulloracle%3A%2F%5E%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%3A.%2B%24%2F+r%3E%3Du&unique=cards&as=grid&order=usd&dir=desc)

Comment: 'ability set similar to chromat' is incredibly vague,

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is [Keeper of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Keeper%20of%20the%20Dead), a black uncommon from before 8th edition with an activated ability, and its art is decently similar to Bog Initiate. Saying this has "an ability set similar to Cromat" is a stretch, but it's by far the best match I could find from an art perspective and its repeatable removal could make it highly sought-after especially if inexperienced players neglect to enforce the extra conditions well.

[Knight of Stromgald](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knight%20of%20Stromgald) is an uncommon mono-black creature from before 8th edition, with multiple activated abilities, and its art shows a single human standing upright centered in front of a monochrome background.

[Nightscape Master](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nightscape%20Master) is a rare mono-black creature from before 8th edition, with multiple activated abilities using different colors of mana and its art depicts a single humanoid (technically a zombie, not a human). This a stretch to say the art is "similar to Bog Initiate", but its ability set is more similar to Cromat than the others.

Lastly, [Avatar of Woe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Avatar%20of%20Woe) is a rare mono-black creature originally printed before 8th edition, which has the same *artist* as Bog Initiate in its initial printing if "similar to Bog Initiate" was more a matter of art style than composition. It has several abilities, though they aren't very similar to Cromat's, and I could see it feeling overpowered if playing casually with friends at school.

If none of these is correct, here is [all black creatures with activated abilities, with alternate arts shown separately](https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&dir=asc&order=released&q=oracle%3A%22%3A%22+type%3Acreature+color%3E%3DB+%28game%3Apaper%29&unique=art) sorted oldest to newest. The card you are looking should be somewhere in there unless your "ability set similar to Cromat" description was wildly inaccurate.